# UDP sendto fails when using specific routing tables

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, udp

I've got a system with multiple interfaces.  I've isolated all of those interfaces from each other using a few `sysctl` options and routing tables and rules.

Each interface has its own routing table defining a default route.

Each routing table has a set of 4 rules that define which packets should go to which table.

For simplification, let's say i have `eth0 (192.168.1.1)` and `eth1 (192.168.1.2)`.

> from `192.168.1.1` table `eth0`
>
> to `192.168.1.1` table `eth0`
>
> iif eth0 `table eth0`
>
> oif eth0 `table eth0`

For `eth2` it's the same.

The `sysctl` options are:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
```

This works excellently for 99% of my intended use cases, but one fails.  If a packet is generated from a socket that is not bound, like replying to a UDP client using "sendto", the call fails with "Network Unreachable".  If a specific IP address is bound before calling sendto, the call succeeds as expected.

Short of setting up a catch-all default route for situations like these, is there anything that can be done using policy routing (e.g. iptables, ip rule) to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: A solution using a mark with iptables won't help. iptables' output mangle hook happens *after* the first route lookup ("routing decision"), and triggers a *second* lookup ("reroute check"). So using iptables's mark won't help here, because "Network is unreachable" happens at the first lookup and the mangle table is never used. See this picture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg

Comment: But adding this catch-all default route, even if you never intend to use it, would then allow using iptables' mark + ip rule fwmark (from the triggered reroute check). I don't know if there's a solution by using iptables for this problem, but a "default" default route is still needed if iptables is involved

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any solution not involving ip tables then?  I wonder why the routing lookup fails if the source address is specified, and i have a rule stating all packets from source address X use table Y

Comment: what about this? `ip link add dummy0 type dummy`; `ip link set dummy0 up`; `ip route add default dev dummy0` . Obviously no packet will go to the wrong place. In my test with socat, I went from "Network is unreachable" to replying with the 192.168.1.1 source  when contacted from the same lan through eth0 to 192.168.1.1. Now it appears to be a simple case. Is there an actual real case? By the way, you didn't write any route in the question, so I can't do more than this here

Comment: ok things work fine for replying (including the udp case). But when initiating an outgoing connection, without stating an IP, it will choose 1st interface's ip (192.168.1.1) and default route interface dummy0. But if I then mark the packet, it triggers a reroute check, and at last follows the expected rules (so switches to eth0), not even the need to add a fwmark rule, the reroute alone does it.